# Как настроить кнопку в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть вот такой код:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

// Performs a mouse look.

public class FPSInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed_run;
    public float jumpPower;
    private float gravity_character;
    private Vector3 move_vector;
    private CharacterController My_controller;

    private void Start()
    {
        My_controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        PlayerMove();
        Gravity();
    }

    private void PlayerMove()
    {
        move_vector = Vector3.zero;
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Up"))
        {
            move_vector.x = speed_run;
        }
        if (Vector3.Angle(Vector3.forward, move_vector) > 1f ||
            Vector3.Angle(Vector3.forward, move_vector) == 0)
        {
            Vector3 direct =
                Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, move_vector, speed_run, 0.0f);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direct);
        }

        move_vector.y = gravity_character;
        My_controller.Move(move_vector * Time.deltaTime); // Move player
    }

    private void Gravity()
    {
        if (!My_controller.isGrounded) gravity_character -= 20f * Time.deltaTime;
        else gravity_character = -1f;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && My_controller.isGrounded)
        {
            gravity_character = jumpPower;
        }
    }
}
```

он включён в игрока. Но при запуске выходит такая ошибка:

```
ArgumentException: Input Button Up is not setup.
 To change the input settings use: Edit -> Project Settings -> Input
FPSInput.PlayerMove () (at Assets/FPSInput.cs:28)
FPSInput.Update () (at Assets/FPSInput.cs:21)
```

Подскажите новичку как настроить кнопку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключается в этой строке:

```
Input.GetButtonDown("Up")
```

А значит она следующее, Unity не понимает какую кнопку вы имеете в виду. Все возможные кнопки, на которые реагирует метод `Input.GetButtonDown()`, указываются в настройках Input проекта. Как раз туда вас Unity и пытается отправить (Edit -> Project Settings -> Input).
[image: Окно настроек проекта]
В этом окне вы можете добавить соответствующую кнопку с названием "Up", по умолчанию такой кнопки в этом списке нет. По этому, когда Unity доходит до вызова метода `Input.GetButtonDown()`, то ищет указанное значение "Up" именно в этих настройках. Вы можете добавить новую кнопку с таким названием в этих настройках или изменить параметр, с которым вызываете `Input.GetButtonDown()`, что ваша ошибка больше не появлялась.

Все, указанные здесь кнопки не являются реальными клавишами на клавиатуре или кнопками мыши, это - виртуальные кнопки. Вы можете настроить эти виртуальные кнопки так, чтобы они соответствовали нужным клавишам клавиатуры или кнопкам мыши или кнопкам других контроллеров (например гейм-падов). Это сделано для того, чтобы унифицировать управление вашей игрой в независимости от того, каким устройством ввода вы пользуетесь.

Если остались вопросы по поводу Input, можете посмотреть [официальный туториал](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qf3Oo3BW83Y) по этой теме (на простом английском).

Если добавление кнопки - не то, что вам требуется, и вы хотите просто обрабатывать нажатие какой-либо клавиши клавиатуры, воспользуйтесь [Input.GetKeyDown()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html).